# Создание песочницы на c#

Tags: c#, песочница

Основная задача изоляция программы от операционной системы, как это делает Sandboxie, но мне нужно чтобы программа выполняла код в реальной ОС. Например: Программа запущенная в песочнице показывает MessageBox и сама песочница показывает этот MessageBox в реальной ОС. Возможно ли такое реализовать на C#, может кто знает какие статьи почитать или ссылки на исходники?

Comment: Ваш вопрос слишком общий для so. А почитать можно например отсюда: https://habr.com/ru/post/434138/

Comment: Может просто запустить на виртуалке удаленной или просто удаленной машине?

Comment: Нет, мне нужно запустить программу в виртуальной среде и выполнять ее в реальной ОС.

Answer (score 1):

В .NET приложения запускаются в рамках так называемых *доменов приложений* (application domains). Изоляция приложений выполняется именно на этом уровне.

Каждый домен приложения имеет *права*, которые можно ограничивать. *Песочница* в терминах .NET означает, что ваше приложение создаёт новый домен с ограниченными правами и запускает потенциально опасный код там.

Можно ограничивать сборки, которые можно подгружать, можно ограничивать папку на диске, доступную для приложения (оно не сможет читать и писать файлы в других папках) и так далее.

Тема на самом деле обширная, потребует изучения большого количества материалов. Начинать можно [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/app-domains/application-domains). Про создание доменов см. метод `CreateDomain` по ссылке, особенно перегрузку, которая позволяет задавать параметры домена.